# How to group the values from map based on some particualar values?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have values coming from map like the following

```
Key = 1_1, Value = 02/04/2012
Key = 1_2, Value = 03/04/2012
Key = 1_3, Value = 04/04/2012
Key = 1_4, Value = 05/04/2012
Key = 1_5, Value = 06/04/2012
Key = 1_6, Value = 09/04/2012
Key = 1_7, Value = 10/04/2012
Key = 1_8, Value = 11/04/2012
Key = 1_9, Value = 12/04/2012
Key = 1_10, Value = 13/04/2012
Key = 1_11, Value = 18/04/2012
Key = 1_12, Value = 19/04/2012
Key = 1_13, Value = 20/04/2012
Key = 1_14, Value = 23/04/2012
Key = 1_15, Value = 24/04/2012
Key = 1_16, Value = 25/04/2012
Key = 1_17, Value = 26/04/2012
Key = 1_18, Value = 27/04/2012
Key = 1_19, Value = 30/04/2012
Key = 10_20, Value = 02/04/2012
Key = 10_21, Value = 03/04/2012
Key = 10_22, Value = 04/04/2012
Key = 10_23, Value = 05/04/2012
Key = 10_24, Value = 06/04/2012
Key = 10_25, Value = 09/04/2012
Key = 10_26, Value = 10/04/2012
Key = 10_27, Value = 11/04/2012
Key = 10_28, Value = 12/04/2012
Key = 10_29, Value = 13/04/2012
Key = 10_30, Value = 16/04/2012
Key = 10_31, Value = 17/04/2012
Key = 10_32, Value = 18/04/2012
Key = 10_33, Value = 19/04/2012
Key = 10_34, Value = 23/04/2012
Key = 10_35, Value = 24/04/2012
Key = 10_36, Value = 26/04/2012
Key = 10_37, Value = 27/04/2012
```

I am really struggling to separate these values and put them in separate map.

i would like to group as follows.

1_1 to 1_19 this i want to split based on "_" and get the first value alone and group them in to a separate map.

like 1 is key and the value will be the date.

EDIT:

```
employeeMap =  showExelData(sheetData);
        String previousEemployeeID = "",employeeID[];
        Iterator<Map.Entry> entries = employeeMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = entries.next();
            employeeID = entry.getKey().toString().split("_");

                // this is the place where i want to check the values if 1 than group the values it can be even  Key = 1_0, Value = 25/04/2012 to  If Key = 1_18, Value = 30/04/2012
     but when the other one comes ex :  Key = 10_0, Value = 25/04/2012 to  If Key = 10_17, Value = 30/04/2012it has to go to new Map
```

this is the place where i am lacking.
        }

Comment: `HashMap`s require the `key` to be unique. Having 19 keys being equal to `1` will not work with `HashMap`s.

Comment: You are rather unspecific what do you mean by "*group them in a separate map*". Would you like a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` so that `outer.get("1").get("3").equals("04/04/2012")`? Or would you rather like a `Map<String, Collection<String>>` where you simply have several values per key.

Comment: @nd thanks for the comment, i have several values as described above and i want to group those values in separate map as it is but one map will have entire value set of ex : 1_1 to 1_19 and second map will have 10_1 to 10_x likewise i want to group them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split 1_1, 1_2 up to 1_19.. use the split() function of the String class.

Ex.

```
String x = 1_19;

String[] y = x.split("_");
```

y[0] would be equal to 1 and y[1] would be 19

As for using the first value for a key in a map, that would not be possible because it requires a unique key for every entry in the map just like what npinti commented on your post.

```
public class Mapping {

    Map<String, String> coMap;
    List<String> coList;

    public Mapping() 
    {
        init();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Mapping oMapping = new Mapping();

        Map<String, Map<String, String>> oMap = oMapping.classifyMapEntries();

        for ( String sParentKey : oMapping.coList )
        {
            Map<String, String> oChildMap = oMap.get(sParentKey);
            Iterator<String> oIterator = oChildMap.keySet().iterator();

            System.out.println("Map");
            while( oIterator.hasNext() )
            {
                String sChildKey = oIterator.next();
                System.out.print( "Key: " + sChildKey + ", Value: " 
                                    + oChildMap.get(sChildKey) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    private void init()
    {
        coMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        coList = new ArrayList<String>();

        coMap.put("1_1", "a");
        coMap.put("1_19", "a");
        coMap.put("10_1", "b");
        coMap.put("10_19", "b");
    }

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> classifyMapEntries()
    {
        Map<String, Map<String, String>> oClassified = 
            new HashMap<String, Map<String,String>>();

        Iterator<String> oIterator = coMap.keySet().iterator();
        while( oIterator.hasNext() )
        {
            String sKey = oIterator.next();

            String sFirst = sKey.substring(0,sKey.indexOf("_"));
            if ( !coList.contains(sFirst) )
            {
                coList.add(sFirst);
            }
        }

        for ( String sKey : coList )
        {
            Map<String, String> oChildMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

            Iterator<String> oIterator2 = coMap.keySet().iterator();
            while( oIterator2.hasNext() )
            {
                String sChildKey = oIterator2.next();
                String sParentKey = sChildKey.substring(0,sChildKey.indexOf("_"));

                if ( sKey.equals(sParentKey) )
                {
                    oChildMap.put(sChildKey, coMap.get(sChildKey));
                }
            }

            oClassified.put(sKey, oChildMap);
        }

        return oClassified;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes key is unique,my problem is i want to group the values which has got 1_x and put them in a separate hasmap(making the key unique) or arraylist, i have done this split also but lacking in grouping the similar values.

Comment: Then your problem is solved. upon getting similar keys when splitting and checking the key value, you may now group them in different maps. The checking comes when you split the string with "_" character. If the array[0] is similar then put that in a different map. Did I answer your question?

Comment: thanks, but i am sorry to say that i could not get you could you share the code. what you have given as a answer i do follow the same thing but i really don't know the next part of comparing and grouping them to different map. Please

Comment: Please spare some time for me to get this sort out

Comment: Please see my edit. This code is the simplest that i could give you. I hope this helps.

Comment: I accepted your answer and please do let me know what else i am supposed to do to get you more reputations?

Comment: Oh it's fine. Im glad that I was able to help. No worries.

Comment: what a simple solution to offer someone who is really a beginner, salute to you friend

Answer (score 1):

From the clarification of comment I assume that you would like to filter your keys: one map containing only the keys starting with `1_`, another one with `10_`, etc.

Using plain Java, you can do this by using a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` and iterating over the original map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> filtered = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
for (Entry<String, String> sourceEntry : source.entrySet()) {
  String keyPart = sourceEntry.getKey().split("_")[0];
  Map<String, String> filteredTarget = filtered.get(keyPart);
  if (filteredTarget == null) {
    filteredTarget = new HashMap<String, String>();
    filtered.put(keyPart, filteredTarget);
  }
  filteredTarget.put(sourceEntry.getKey(), sourceEntry.getValue());
}

Map<String, String> oneMap = filtered.get("1");
assert oneMap.get("1_19").equals("30/04/2012");
assert filtered.get("10").get("10_37").equals("27/04/2012");
```

Please note that subsequent changes in the source map or in the filtered map don't update the other map. If you would like to have something like that, than *[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)* can help:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> filtered = Maps.newHashMap();
for (Entry<String, String> sourceEntry : source.entrySet()) {
  final String keyPart = sourceEntry.getKey().split("_")[0];
  Map<String, String> filteredTarget = filtered.get(keyPart);
  if (filteredTarget == null) {
    filteredTarget = Maps.filterKeys(source, new Predicate<String>() {

      @Override
      public boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.startsWith(keyPart + "_");
      }

    });
    filtered.put(keyPart, filteredTarget);
  }
}

Map<String, String> oneMap = filtered.get("1");
assert oneMap.get("1_19").equals("30/04/2012");
assert filtered.get("10").get("10_37").equals("27/04/2012");

oneMap.put("1_50", "Test");
assert source.get("1_50").equals("Test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a `Map` of MapS, where the key for the outer Map is the first number of the keys of the given Map. The code below is not tested, but you can take it as a hint...

```
Map<String, Date> givenMap; // this is the given Map
Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Date> > newMap = new HashMap<Integer, Map<Integer, Date> > ();
for (Map.Entry<String, Date> entry : givenMap.entrySet()) {
    String givenKey = entry.getKey();
    Date givenDate = entry.getValue();
    String[] splittedKey = givenKey.split("_");
    int newOuterKey = Integer.parseInt(splittedKey[0]);
    int newInnerKey = Integer.parseInt(splittedKey[1]);
    if (!newMap.containsKey(newOuterKey)) {
        newMap.put(newOuterKey, new HashMap<Integer, Date> ();
    }
    newMap.get(newOuterKey).put(newInnerKey, givenDate);
}
```